# Undefined index when processing php with input elements having same name in html

Tags: php, html

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="gender">Gender&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="gender">&nbsp; Male &nbsp;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="gender">Female</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Trying to process in php on submit as:

```
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
echo $gender;
```

and getting  Undefined index: gender error
I am guessing the error could be due to same name="gender" for both the buttons. 
Please help me with a solution!

Comment: You seem to have confused `label` with `fieldset`/`legend`.

Comment: Note that it's not an *error* but a *notice* that the server did not receive any POST parameter named 'gender'. You have to check that it exists before asking to get it. See [PHP isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). There are more problems with what you are doing, mainly that you are not sending any data to the server and that you have 2 buttons with the same name (that's not why you get the notice in php)

Comment: Your buttons won't do anything (unless you have some JavaScript you aren't sharing with us), so it isn't clear how you trigger the submit that gives you the PHP notice. You should also show us the HTML for the form itself. You need to give us a complete reduced test case, since you won't get the symptoms you describe with the code you've given.

Comment: [**Your answer is here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26611375/) - Reload the answer if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a value to both buttons.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="gender">Gender&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="gender" value="male">&nbsp; Male &nbsp;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="gender" value="female">Female</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your form method set to? Also, is the php code you wrote in the file called by the action attribute in the form?

Comment: That's because your name value needs to be `gender` in both buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no FORM tag found in the above code. If you want to get value with $_POST, you need  FORM around your DIV. Also, you need VALUE attributes.

```
<form method="POST">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend for="gender">Gender&nbsp;&nbsp;</legend>
        <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="gender[]" value='Male'>&nbsp; Male &nbsp;</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="gender[]" value='Female'>Female</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now `$_POST['gender']` would be an array.

**N.B.:** If `<button type="button"` does not work, then use `<button type="submit"`

Comment: This is partially correct, since OP hasn't posted full code, if any.

Comment: `type="button"` needs to be `type="submit"` in order for it to work properly, otherwise it won't do anything.

Comment: Isn't tag Button contains the function of submitting by default?

Comment: No it doesn't. Try it and see; I have and I knew it even before testing it. I've been dealing with forms for many years. ;)

Comment: Yep, commonly I use INPUT tag instead of BUTTON tag. When I use BUTTON tag, I do not set the TYPE attribute.

Comment: `<input type="submit">` as well, yes. But as I said, I always test everything, and while testing it a few minutes ago, `type="button"` did not work, but `type="submit"` did. Maybe why OP hasn't said anything, hard to say if OP did see your answer or not. I've made an edit in your answer to that effect.

Comment: Yes, the submit type is needed, you are right. Maybe OP is trying hard to test all the possible solutions.